# React-Motion Spring component causing Invariant Violation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-motion

I have (had) a working React component that just displayed a small string wrapped in a header tag.  Since it *was* displaying properly, I am almost positive my import/export is set up correctly.  When I try to add a `<Spring />` component to my `render()` method, I am presented with:

`Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of Animation`.

Why would the `<Spring>` component cause this to happen when everything was working correctly before?  My code below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Spring } from 'react-motion';

class Animation extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Spring defaultValue={0} endValue={120}>
        {val => {
          let style = {
            height: val,
            position: 'absolute'
          }
          return <div style={style}><h1>Hi!</h1></div>
        }}
      </Spring>
    )
  }
}

export default Animation;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

react-motion is no longer expose `Spring` function that takes props and context to be used as React Component, instead you got **three** functions that you can use `Motion`, `StaggeredMotion`, and `TransitionMotion` in addition to `spring` function (*with lowercase 's'*) that takes value and config. Check the latest docs on [react-motion](https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion) repo on Github.